# dynamic graphic representation for extended dijkstra's algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, graphic, dynamic-library

I am working on a project which requires to show the output of the extended Dijkstra's algorithm in a dynamic form. I tried and till now i am getting static graphs only. By dynamic I mean that I want to show nodes traveling through the relevant path according to the algorithm **Using java** language, as the Dijkstra is also in java. So how and which libraries can I be using? A detailed description would be nice. Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not clear, are you struggling with implementing the algorithm? with finding the path? visualizing it?

Comment: not the code. I need a way to implement the visualizzation effect, as in the traveling of the packets from 1 node to another.

Answer (score 0):

In order to visualize the inner workings of an algorithm, you will have to implement the algorithm yourself. If you use a library, you will not have access to the internal variables (such as the "nodes traveling through the relevant path").

Best advice: Find a visualization of some path algorithm written in Java. Study the code and see how it works. Then implement Dijkstra's algorithm in Java (make sure it is correct). Finally add the visualization code.

Comment: but is it possible in java to implement dynamic representation?

Comment: As an animation? Yes.